# Trying to deploy React app on heroku. App's api works fine locally but when I deploy to heroku the api doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, heroku, server, create-react-app, http-proxy-middleware

I am using Node+Express for my back-end. At first I tried using "proxy": http://localhost:3001 in the react client's package.json but that caused an **Invalid Host Header** message when I tried to open my site on heroku.

I followed these [insturctions](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development) which then lead me to using http-proxy-middleware which is where I am at.

This is my setupProxy.js which sits on /src in my app.

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use('/api/*', proxy({
    target: 'https://safe-crag-59591.herokuapp.com',
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    router: {
      'localhost:3000': 'http://localhost:3001'
    }
  }));
};
```

When I deploy it to heroku the front-end works fine. But when I try to make any api call I receive HTTP 400 error messages. The request headers look fine (ex/ header: https://safe-crag-59591.herokuapp.com/api/getAllProduct) but when I try to use any of the routes in Postman I am hit with the same error.

Here is an example of the error in the heroku logs:

```
at=info method=GET path="/api/getAllProduct" host=safe-crag-59591.herokuapp.com request_id=e1455e5b-91fc-418b-a379-98af1012f3d7 fwd="72.207.123.175, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72, 54.146.242.72,54.146.242.72" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4213ms status=400 bytes=2757 protocol=https
```

I am fairly new to this so I am sure there is something I am missing but I feel like I have tried everything.

EDIT: I forgot to add when the server is ran and it sets up the proxy it displays this message in the console:
`[HPM] Proxy created: /  -> https://safe-crag-59591.herokuapp.com`
when I think it should be this based on my setupProxy.js
`[HPM] Proxy created: /api  -> https://safe-crag-59591.herokuapp.com`
But again this is still fairly new to me. Just the other ways I tried setting up my setupProxy.js when the proxy would set up the console would display '/api'.

Comment: You shouldn't run the webpack dev server in production. If you have an Express backend and a React frontend, the easiest thing to do in production is serve the built frontend *from the backend*, then use relative routes.